# Why does trying to release this Node-MySQL pool cause an error?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

This is the first time I've tried connection pooling.

I designed a Node.js database connection module to create a single connection, which is referenced in a pooling function to be used later when passed to various modules.

```
/* Database Connection */

//REQUIRE CUSTOM MODULES

var mysql = require('mysql');

//DEFINE HELPER FUNCTIONS

function createPool() {
    var pool = mysql.createPool({
        dateStrings : true,
        host : '****',
        user : '****',
        password : '****',
        database : '****'
    });
    return pool;
}

function queryFunc(connection, query, callback) {
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            connection.release();
            callback(rows);
        }
    });
}

//CREATE POOL

var pool = createPool();

//DEFINE MODULE EXPORTS

var connection = {};

connection.connect = function(query, callback) {
    if ( typeof query !== 'undefined') {
        debug.log('Performing Query: ' + query);

        //get connection via pool
        var connection = pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            debug.log("New connection pool pulled");
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {

                //otherwise run all queries
                var qComplete = 0;
                queryFunc(connection, query, callback);
            }
        });
    } else {
        debug.log('Oops! Tried to perform an empty query...');
    }
};

module.exports.connection = connection;
```

Usage:

```
var connection = require('connection.js').connection;

connection.connect(...);
```

And it tries to run the query (I know because I had to fix bad queries that it complained about) but gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Object # has no method 'release'
```

**Did I build this pooling module wrong?** If so, how can this be done correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the [Javascript variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variable_scope).  When you declare:

```
var connection = pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {...
```

inside the `connect` function, this `conection` variable will be initialized with the return value of `pool.getConnection`. The problem is that you're passing `connection` to another function inside the same scope:

```
queryFunc(connection, query, callback);
```

Based on what you explained, your module is ok, and you don't need this internal declaration of `connection`, so you could just rip it off:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {...
```

, and now `queryFunc` will receive the correct `connection`.

In case you really need to attribute the return value of `pool.getConnection` to some var, just use another name.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? I was sure that you were right (I mean what else could it be?) *but* I changed that line to `pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {` and I'm getting the exact same error.

Comment: Really weird @MediaWebDev. I've tested your code, just changing the `'connection.js'` to `'./connection'`, and it worked like a charm. I'm using MySQL 5.5.

Comment: In that case, I must have some sort of update problem. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: I don't know if it's an update problem, but with a simple query like `'SELECT 1 + 1 AS SOLUTION'` it works.